# Circular import in Django framework

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to run a client-server application using Django. When I am trying to run my server in Django, it is giving me the following error.

```sh
raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'blog.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\adimin\\projects\\Portfolio\\blog\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in
 it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

The project urls.py:

```
django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('blog.urls'))
]
```

The application(blog.urls):

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path


urlsPatterns = [path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
                path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(),
                name='post_detail'),
]
```

App's views.py:

```
 from django.views import generic
    from .models import Post
    
    class PostList(generic.ListView):
        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        template_name = 'index.html'
    
    class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

Kindly, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your import in your `urls.py` is incorrect:

```
 django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls'))
```

Should be:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

**EDIT**

Your `blogs.urls` does not have a valid urlpatterns variable in it. Changing the variable name should fix it.

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

Comment: See my editted answer. Let me know if works for you or not.

Comment: unfortunately its not.

Comment: It actually worked,the issue was on the templates....thanks